# Bootstrap glyphicon checkbox CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I need to do bootstrap glyphicon checkbox

```
 <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value=""/>
    To Download<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></div>
</label>
```

But i want to put glyphicon to place of checkbox. Thanks in advance for answers

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t7gAR/579/

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work..

**The working code snippet**

```css
.glyphicon:before {
 visibility: visible;
}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-download:checked:before {
   content: "\e013";
}
input[type=checkbox].glyphicon{
    visibility: hidden;
    
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="glyphicon glyphicon-download" value=""/>
    To Download
</label>
</body>
</html>
```